# Why is my upload directory relative to the project directory but Django is trying to get it from an app related path?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am building a Dev-blog to store and refer to project I've coded for my portfolio, and I've been trying to add a media upload capability to my post text boxes. I started off by using a standard RichTextField, which had a built-in function to add Images through URL(No uploading).
It worked fine, but I wanted the ability to upload photos from my machine.

The blog is fully operational (on a local server for development), so all irrelevant code was disregarded.

The only problem is with setting the paths to my image files.

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.urls import reverse
    from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
    
    class Post(models.Model):
        author=models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title= models.CharField(max_length=40)
        text = RichTextUploadingField()
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
        publication_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    
        def publish(self):
            self.publication_date=timezone.now()
            self.save()
    
        def approve_comment(self):
            return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    
        def ckeditor_upload(self):
            return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include,re_path
    from django.contrib.auth import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('blog.urls')),
        path('accounts/login/',views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'),name='login'),
        path('accounts/logout/',views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}), #{'next_page':'/'} makes it go back to homepage
        re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    
    ]
```

```
**settings.py**
<pre>

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'blog'
]

#
#
#

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'media/uploads'
```

```
The file is being uploaded to a new media directory in the project folder, but it is trying to load it from within the app folder. 
<pre>
[20/Sep/2021 02:58:14] "POST /ckeditor/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 86
Not Found: /media/uploads/2021/09/20/kaki.jpg
[20/Sep/2021 02:58:14] "GET /media/uploads/2021/09/20/kaki.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4602
Not Found: /media/uploads/2021/09/20/kaki.jpg
[20/Sep/2021 02:58:14,942] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 54571)
```

**What I've tried:**

- `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'blog/media/uploads'` - Same results but inside the blog(app) folder.
- Moving the image file manually to the apps media directory - the image loaded, but that's kinda pointless
- Adding root variables

  ```
  MEDIA_URL='/media/'
  MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'blog/media')
  CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
  ```

  - Same error

  ```
  [20/Sep/2021 03:34:48] "POST /ckeditor/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 95
  Not Found: /blog/media/uploads/2021/09/20/linkdn.jpg
  [20/Sep/2021 03:34:48] "GET /blog/media/uploads/2021/09/20/linkdn.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4623
  Not Found: /blog/media/uploads/2021/09/20/linkdn.jpg
  [20/Sep/2021 03:34:48] "GET /blog/media/uploads/2021/09/20/linkdn.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4623
  ```
- Tried looking in the docs

```
Add a CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH setting to the project’s settings.py file. This setting specifies a relative path to your CKEditor media upload directory. CKEditor uses Django’s storage API. By default, Django uses the file system storage backend (it will use your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL) and if you don’t use a different backend you have to have write permissions for the CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH path within MEDIA_ROOT, i.e.:

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

When using default file system storage, images will be uploaded to the “uploads” folder in your MEDIA_ROOT and URLs will be created against MEDIA_URL (/media/uploads/image.jpg).

If you want to be able to have control over filename generation, you have to add a custom filename generator to your settings:
```

- Nothing worked.

- Tried uploading to statics - Made a total mess.

**Guiding questions:**

- If `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH` is the upload path, Can I specify a load path, or am I left with `MEDIA ROOT`
- I there a default value controlling the load path?
- Is there maybe a different Rich text and upload box that will fit better?

**Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!<3**

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) #Without this the MEDIA's URL is not recognized!!!
```

Was not added to URLs, thus the URL was not recognized at form request!

Comment: static is a function? must be imported?